# Dataverse to Synapse Link - missing Lake database in Workspace

Tags: powerapps, azure-synapse, dataverse, powerapps-modeldriven

I was able to successfully configure link integration between Dataverse and Azure Synapse. The data flow between Dataverse and the Lake works and I can see files with data from Dataverse inside my Azure Storage.

My problem is that when I'm opening the Synapse Analytics Studio and connecting to my Synapse Workspace I should be able to see (according all the documentation and all the videos I was able to found, for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s0amKYC7uiA) new lake database with the name of my Dataverse environment in the Data-> Workspace section. Mine one is empty. However I'm able to see the files with Dataverse data inside "Linked" section.

[image]

Am I missing some configuration step? Any idea what could be the reason of this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
It occurs that the managed resource group used by Azure Synapse Workspace was not in the same location as a Workspace itself and the Database environment. After fixing this I've got access to the lake db.

Comment: Hi - do you have specifics? I have them both in the same location UK south and still not showing up for me